# Collision in full duplex

Tags: networking, switch, local-area-network

I have been reading about full duplex and the fact that there are two lines of data, one for receiving and one for sending information and because of that there is no need for collision detection (collision is not possible). I am having a tough time figuring a case when there are multiple devices sending information to the same target device. Wouldn't there be a collision at the receiving line ?

**Example**

> Devices A, B and C are connected to the single switch. Devices A and B
>   are sending a frame to the device C (at roughly the same time). How is
>   this handled and why is there no collision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read about [collision domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_domain). In a switched network, each port of the switch is considered to be having its own collision domain. So, no traffic on a port may collide with any other port.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have been reading about collision domains as well and understand the consequences of the concept. In factm I understand the concept when there are no switches (there is a single line). The thing I do not understand is how one port is considered to be the collision domain on the physical level when there is a single line for listening connected from the device to the switch? (Does the switch not send two different sourced frames at the same time through the link?)

Comment: @KostaS.: The switch receives data framed and "read" them to determine the destination port (MAC table). It does not just emits what it receives from one port to the other (like Ethernet Hub).

Comment: What happens if switch receives two frames from separate senders and determines that destination port for both frames is the same?

Comment: @KostaS.: It simply sends them one after the other after. The switch (after receiving a frame) can buffer, validate, and then forward the frame.